# ViewPager slide to next image when clicking on right side of screen

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have a ViewPager of images, and I want to make it slide in the following way:
If I click on the right (left) side of the screen, go to previous (next) image. It's like the screen is two halves and each half moves to a direction on click.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

You can [get Disaplay width](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1016941/799799)

Then you can override [onTouchEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) in your viewpager.

When you get MotionEvent object - you can get 'tap' coordinates and you will be able to understand on wich side of screen user clicked and handle it.

Comment: Will this interfere with the normal sliding of the ViewPager?

Comment: It depends. When you override onTouchEvent you should return boolean flag: True if the event was handled, false otherwise.
If you will call 'return super.onTouchEvent(event)' - both ways will work (i am not sure but you can try).

Answer (score 0):

Set on touch listener for your `ViewPager` or contentview of `ViewPager` item.

Take the half of the screen/view width, check if `event.getX()` is greater than the half value, if so, go to next, otherwise to the previous.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev) {
    if(ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        mDownX = ev.getX();
        mDownY = ev.getY();
        isOnClick = true;
    }else if(ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ){
        if (isOnClick ) {
               if(ev.getX() > mViewPager.getWidth()/2) {
                  //go to next
               }else{
                 //go to previous
                  }
               return true;

        }
    }else if(ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){    
     if (isOnClick && (Math.abs(mDownX - ev.getX()) > DRAG_THRESHOLD || Math.abs(mDownY - ev.getY()) > DRAG_THRESHOLD)) {
        isOnClick = false;
        return false;
    }


 }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Will this interfere with the normal sliding of the ViewPager?